# graphic issues debian jessie

Tags: graphics-card, firmware, debian-jessie

I have some graphic issues on my laptop, low resolution and no possibility to link other VGA monitor.

```
root@random:~# lspci -nn | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 630M] [10de:0de9] (rev a1)
root@random:~# 

root@random:~# lshw -c video | grep configuration 
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0


root@random:~# cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

It is possible that xorg.conf is somewhere wrong?

```
random@random:~$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
XWAYLAND0 connected 1360x768+0+0 340mm x 190mm
   1360x768@0.1Hz   0.00*+

root@random:~# uname -a
Linux random 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1 (2015-05-24) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a problem with using proprietary software I'd recommend using the drivers that Nvidia provide for GNU/Linux. They are usually on par with their Windows counterparts.

I tried to use nouveau on my MacBook Pro some time back, but encountered a lot of issues (flickering and other graphical artifacts). I eventually gave up and resorted to using the Nvidia drivers.

Comment: I have no problem to use proprietary driver but they cause me some issue, I've tried to install nVidia driver (consulting the wiki) but no lucky at present. I also tried to install bumblebee but the grapich is even distorted with a very low resolution and other issues.

Comment: Did you use the one from nvidia.com or the one in the non-free repos?

Comment: non-free repository

Comment: I usually use the one from nvidia.com (you'll have to compile a kernel module), which works fine.